# How can I add disparate chunks to a PdfPCell using iTextSharp?

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, chunks

How can I concatenate disparate chunks and add them to a paragraph, the paragraph to a cell, then the cell to a table using iTextSharp (in generating a PDF file)?

I am able to get to a certain "place" in my PDF file generation, so that it looks like so (the right side of the page is blank, as it should be):

[image]

This is the code I'm using for that:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25))
    {
        //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
        {

            //Open the document for writing
            doc.Open();

            var courierBold11Font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 11, BaseColor.BLACK);
            var docTitle = new Paragraph("Mark Twain", courierBold11Font);
            doc.Add(docTitle);

            var timesRoman9Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Times Roman", 9, BaseColor.BLACK);
            var subTitle = new Paragraph("Roughing It", timesRoman9Font);
            doc.Add(subTitle);

            var courier9RedFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Courier", 9, BaseColor.RED);
            var importantNotice = new Paragraph("'All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard' - Scotty Briggs", courier9RedFont);
            importantNotice.Leading = 0;
            importantNotice.MultipliedLeading = 0.9F; // reduce the width between lines in the paragraph with these two settings

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell cellImportantNote = new PdfPCell(importantNotice);
            cellImportantNote.BorderWidth = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
            table.WidthPercentage = 50;
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            table.AddCell(cellImportantNote);
            doc.Add(table);

            doc.Close();
        }
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        String PDFTestOutputFileName = String.Format("iTextSharp_{0}.pdf", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
        PDFTestOutputFileName = PDFTestOutputFileName.Replace(":", "_");
        var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), PDFTestOutputFileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} written", PDFTestOutputFileName));
    }
}
```

However, I need to break up the red text so that part of it is bolded, parts of it are anchor tags/hrefs, etc.

I thought I could do it this way:

```
var courier9RedBoldFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER_BOLD, 9, BaseColor.RED);
// Build up chunkified version of "important notice"
Chunk boldpart = new Chunk("All down but nine - set 'em up on the other alley, pard", courier9RedBoldFont);
Chunk attribution = new Chunk("Scotty Briggs", courier9RedFont);

PdfPTable tbl = new PdfPTable(1);
tbl.WidthPercentage = 50;
tbl.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
var par = new Paragraph();
par.Chunks.Add(boldpart);
par.Chunks.Add(attribution );
PdfPCell chunky = new PdfPCell(par);
chunky.BorderWidth = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
tbl.AddCell(chunky);                          
doc.Add(tbl);
```

...but that's not adding anything at all to the PDF file, but why not? Doesn't a cell take a paragraph, and cannot a paragraph be comprised of Chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `para.Chunks.Add()` just use `par.Add();` The `Chunks` that are returned from `Paragraph` actually come from the base class `Phrase`. If [you look at the code](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Phrase.cs#l216) for that property you'll see that the collection returned is actually a temporary collection created on the fly so it is effectively read-only.